# Webkit JavaScript Fullscreen on canvas does not work

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, fullscreen

i am trying to make a canvas fullscreen via javascript.

While in firefox it works fine, in chrome it does not.

This is what i do:

```
document.addEventListener('webkitfullscreenchange', function(e) {
    var canv = gamvas.getCanvas();
    if (canv) {
        if (document.webkitIsFullScreen) {
            gamvas._isFullScreen = true;
            canv.style.width=screen.width+'px';
            canv.style.height=screen.height+'px';
        } else {
            gamvas._isFullScreen = false;
            canv.style.width=canv.width+'px';
            canv.style.height=canv.height+'px';
        }
    }
}, false);
```

Then when i use canvas.webkitRequestFullscreen() the code above is called, it has the correct screen.width/height of the desktop, but it seems as the result is scaled. So either the browser sets a screenmode less then the desktop, or it upscales the canvas. The result is that the canvas does not match onto the screen and part flows over the right and lower screen border.

I have tried to work with -webkit-full-screen css to 100%, but while it works on vertical size, it still is off on the horizontal size

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug that has been reported to the Chromium team. You can follow the issue at http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=138368

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
#canvas:-webkit-full-screen {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}
#canvas:-moz-full-screen {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}
```